# How i can smooth a sinusoidal signal using it's local maximum

Tags: smoothing

I have a signal that it is like a Sinusoidal signal with many local maximum, I want to smooth this signal with almost connecting it's local maximum to each other.

Comment: Hi Omid, I think you could get more useful answers to your question if you formulated your goals a bit more clearly. What do you mean by 'almost connecting it's local maximum'? The easiest way would simply be to connect the local maxima by straight lines, but this is probably not what you want. So what is it exactly that you want?

Comment: As Matt says, it's hard to divine exactly what you're after. Some pictures of your data and what you want from it might help.  As WebMonster answers, one interpretation of what you're asking is for an ["envelope detector"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector).

Comment: Hi my friends, Thank you for your help, I wanted to load an image but i couldn't. As WebMonster said to me, I wanted an envelop for my signal and with his guide i could find a solution for my problem. Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) to calculate the signal envelope. It is discussed in [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/424/hilbert-transform-to-compute-signal-envelope) question.