# Why do we read that Hilbert transform can be used for envelope detection?

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, sampling, hilbert-transform, amplitude

We can often read that Hilbert transform is useful for envelope detection (e.g.
[Hilbert transform to compute signal envelope?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/424/hilbert-transform-to-compute-signal-envelope))

I have done some tests with various soundfiles, and

```
x[n] -> absolue value -> 1-pole low pass filter -> envelope
```

or

```
x[n] -> Hilbert transform -> absolute value -> 1-pole low pass filter -> envelope
```

gives the same kind of result, it's not better with a Hilbert transform (top : envelope computed with hilbert, bottom : envelope computed without hilbert) :

[image]

Moreover, I know that computing the Hilbert transform is very time-consuming (big FIR filters involved).

So it is really a good method for envelope detection ?

Comment: Why are you filtering *after* taking the modulus of the hilbert transform? Do not do it this way. Instead, low-pass (or band pass) your signal prior, perform the hilbert transform, and take the modulus to get the envelope.

Comment: Thanks user4619, I tried, but this doesn't give good results... Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/kz2yhHu3. Do you have an idea of what to modify ? (Unfortunately I cannot paste a figure.png here in the comment to show you the result !)

Comment: What is the nature of your data? Is it narrow-band, or is it broad-band? Usually voice is broadband, in which case you cannot use the Hilbert Transform.

Comment: A few weeks ago I needed it for broadband, but now for narrow-band : I need the envelope of a single harmonic of a soundfile, example : I need the envelop of a signal whose spectrum is 470-500 Hz

Comment: If you bandpass your signal through a filter centered at 485 Hz, with the same bandwidth, computed the hilbert transform, and take the modulus, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Using a Hilbert transform with a sufficiently narrow-band signal, the low pass filter may not be needed even for continuous envelope estimation.

Comment: So you're saying that Hilbert transform is used to avoid the use of low pass filter?

Comment: Avoid the use of a lowpass filter, thanks to Hilbert transform is a bit strange : isn't a 1-pole IIR low pass filter much much faster than a FIR with thousands of coefficients (needed for Hilbert transform)?

Comment: Faster?  Likely yes.  Produce identical results, depending on the signal and the answer required?  Possibly not.

Comment: ok! thanks! I'll investigate more on the hilbert transform then!